# Using a Scrapy pipeline without using settings.py config

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm avoiding using the Scrapy boilerplate generator because my code will be integrated as part of a wider project.

My current project tree is like this:

```
/ test
|- items.py
|- pipelines.py
|- spider.py
```

My `pipeline.py` contains a pipeline that looks like this:

```
import pymongo

class MongoPipeline(object):
    collection_name = 'pages'
    [... rest of the pipeline class ...]
```

How can I use this class in `spider.py` without using a `settings.py` file and `scrapy.conf`?

I've tried importing the pipeline class and setting `ITEM_PIPELINES` in `custom_settings` but that throws `ValueError: Error loading object 'MongoPipeline': not a full path`:

```
from pipelines import MongoPipeline

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'x'
    allowed_domains = ['x']
    start_urls = ['x']

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'MongoPipeline': 100
        }
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'YourProjectName.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 100
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It turned it was only `pipelines.MongoPipeline` for me (or `module.PipelineClass` for the generic case. This is when you're not using a scrapy project to run your spider.

Comment: @Juicy it's just a path to your pipelines.py